# Azure Blob Storage lifecycle management - send report or log after run

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am considering using Azure Blob Storage's build-in lifecycle management feature for deleting blobs of a certain age.
However, due to a business requirement, it must be possible to generate a report or log statement after each daily execution of the defined ruleset. The report or log must state the number of blob blocks that were affected, e.g. deleted during the run.

I have read through the documentation and Googled to see if others have had similar inquiries, but so far without any luck.

So my question: Does any of you know if and how I can get a build-in Lifecycle management system to do one of the following after each daily run:

- Add a log statement to the storage account containing the Blob storage.
- Generate and send a report to an endpoint I define.

If the above can't be done I will have to code the daily deletion job and report generation myself, which surely I can do, but I would like to use the built-in feature if possible.

Comment: You can configure Diagnostics logs. It will record delete action. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account#:~:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%2C%20select,retention%20policy%20for%20the%20data.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @JimXu no, it seems to address my needs. Thanks for the link. If you respond as an answer, I can mark that is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

If you want to know which blobs are deleted every day, we can configure `Diagnostics settings` in the storqge account. After doing that, we will get the logs for read, write, and delete requests for the blob. For more detail, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account#configure-logging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet)

Regarding how to enable it, we can use PowerShell command `Set-AzStorageServiceLoggingProperty`.